# How to achieve Fanatic badge when using multiple devices?

Tags: support, bug

I have never logged out of GL and I usually enter the site using my laptop. When I'm on the road I enter the site from my phone (browser) and I am also perpetually logged in on the phone.

However, if I visit the site for 34 consecutive days from laptop, and the 35th day I visit only on phone, when  enter from laptop on the 36th day the counter is reset to day 1.

The first time it happened I thought it was an error, but I have tested it a few times and keeps repeating. I'll never get the Fanatic badge if I have to use my laptop daily.

What can I do?

Comment: I didn't even notice when I got it... I feel like I logged on only in my phone during some days.

Comment: Don't forget that simply logging in isn't enough.  You have to actually do something on the site to be counted.

Comment: @Chenmunka I was one of the top voters, frequently reaching the daily limit, so I think I actually did something.

Answer (score 4):

It should not matter. The site checks when you load pages in GL if you are logged in. Are you sure that you were logged in on both devices? Going to your personal page is not enough, you need to see also your points on the black bar.

I'm using a lot of computers and devices, and I reached 98 consecutive days, before I forgot (for a few hours) to log in again. For sure I used different computers in weekends and phone on holidays.

I think the "day" start around noon UTC.

Comment: I was sure I was logged in on my phone, but now I'm having doubts seeing that I'm the only one with this error. Maybe I wasn't logged in after all. I think it would be better if I reinstalled the mobile app, just to make sure. As for the day start, it is at midnight UTC for voting. Maybe it is at noon UTC for visiting - I didn't think about it until now. Anyway, thanks for answering my question; it feels good to know people care.

Comment: @Alina: I use mobile web version (I prefer it compared to mobile app).  Here some help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190700/are-consecutive-days-counted-each-24-hours-or-by-utc   So you need to check the questions, not just the homepage.  You are right about 00:00 UTC: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start